# find regex matches from csv and append as new column

Tags: python

What I'm after is to use python to pull out matches against a regular expression which occur in a freetext field of a csv. If a match (or matches) are found, I'd like the script to append these matches in a new column in the csv.

sample csv data:

```
recordID,freetextField

row1,lots of text blah blah blah etc 07635463726 etc etc etc

row2,07938998988 blahblah

row3,07635463726blahblah07635463726
```

desired result:

```
recordID,freetextField,phonenumber1,phonenumber2

row1,lots of text blah blah blah etc 07635463726 etc etc etc,07635463726,

row2,07938998988 blahblah,07938998988

row3,07635463999blahblah07635463726,07635463999,07635463726
```

using a regex along the lines of this:

```
(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Could I nudge your attention to the `re.VERBOSE` flag (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE).  It ought to be mandatory for any but the smallest regexen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something similar to this:

```
outrow = []    
with open("path/to/inputFile.csv", "rb") as fileIn:#input file location
    with open("path/to/outputFile.csv", "wb") as fileOut:#output file location
        writer = csv.writer(fileOut)
        reader = csv.reader(fileIn, delimiter = ',')
        for row in reader:
            recordID = row[0]
            freetextField = row[1]
            phonenumber1 = ''
            phonenumber2 = ''
            for cell in row:
                phonenumber2 = re.findall(r"regex/goes/here",cell)
                outrow
        writer.writerow(["recordID,freetextField,phonenumber1,phonenumber2"])   
        writer.writerow([recordID,freetextField,phonenumber1,phonenumber2])
```

Comment: no problem. If  you like the solution, please accept it/ upvote it.